# Understanding co-efficients of logistic regression R

Tags: r, statistics, logistic-regression

this question is about understanding the logistic regression output using R

here is my sample data frame:

```
    Drugpairs             AdverseEvent  Y    N
1   Rebetol + Pegintron       Nausea   29 1006
2   Rebetol + Pegintron      Anaemia   21 1014
3   Rebetol + Pegintron     Vomiting   14 1021
4   Ribavirin + Pegasys       Nausea    5  238
5   Ribavirin + Pegasys      Anaemia   12  231
6   Ribavirin + Pegasys     Vomiting    1  242
7 Ribavirin + Pegintron       Nausea   15  479
8 Ribavirin + Pegintron      Anaemia    7  487
9 Ribavirin + Pegintron     Vomiting    9  485
```

This basically describes the number of times a particular drug pair has caused a medically adverse event. (Y=yes, N=no). I ran a logistic regression on this data in R using the following commands:

```
mod.form="cbind(Y,N) ~ Drugpairs * AdverseEvent"
glmhepa.out=glm(mod.form, family=binomial(logit), data=hepatitis.df)
```

The summary output was as follows (only showing the co-efficients table)

```
                                                      Estimate Std. Error z value
(Intercept)                                          -3.8771     0.2205 -17.586
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegasys                          0.9196     0.3691   2.491
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegintron                       -0.3652     0.4399  -0.830
AdverseEventNausea                                    0.3307     0.2900   1.140
AdverseEventVomiting                                 -0.4123     0.3479  -1.185
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegasys:AdverseEventNausea      -1.2360     0.6131  -2.016
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegintron:AdverseEventNausea     0.4480     0.5457   0.821
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegasys:AdverseEventVomiting    -2.1191     1.1013  -1.924
DrugpairsRibavirin + Pegintron:AdverseEventVomiting   0.6678     0.6157   1.085
```

I understand that the co-efficients give probabilistic odds. I am curious however, as to why there are no co-efficients for the AdverseEventAnaemea and also why is there no co-efficient for anycombination of the drugs and the adverse event anaemea? (the last 4 rows are the combination effects of drugs and adverse events)

Comment: one factor level, guessing anaemea here, is used as the reference level for which to compare the other adverse events.

Comment: It's debatable as to whether this is on topic here. This is more of an issue of statistical understanding than a programming problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of statistical output. So why not vote to close? The only reason I didn't was because I thought the first answer missed the point.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about statistics.

Comment: *PLEASE* don't crosspost: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93390/understaning-co-efficients-in-summary-output-of-logistic-regression-in-r I agree that this is better at CrossValidated.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients for discrete variables are for effect *differences* (otherwise known as contrasts). The baseline is taken as the lowest level of the factor in the sort order of hte levels vector, alphabetically sorted by default. You cna change the sort ort which will change the refence point and change the coefficeints. With interactions terms such as you have in teh second model you will almost never find it useful to look at the coefficients thems selves. It's going to be better to look at predicted effects for selected comparisons.

And ... don't forget that with logistic modles the coefficients are estimated on the log0odds scale. This will make the use of predict even more helpful because with `predict.glm` using `type= "response"` allows you to report the effects on a probability scale.

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the comment of rawr, it's a matter of degrees of freedom. Consider for example a model

```
lm(height ~ sex, data = dat)
```

Where the sex variable is a factor with levels male and female. The output of the model would show an intercept, and one coefficient - if male is the base level then only the female coefficient would be shown. This is because the male effect is captured by the intercept.

Another way to show the same model is

```
lm(height ~ 0 + sex, data = dat)
```

This would give a model with coefficients for male and female, but no intercept.